# Android UI is freezing when service executes several high loaded threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My android application implements data protection and working with cloud. 
**Application consists of UI and standalone service (runing in own process).**
I'm using IPC(Messages & Handlers) to communicate between UI and service.

I have the next situation - before make some work with data i need to know about data size and data items count (i have to enumerate contacts, photos, etc and collect total information for progresses).

**About problem:**
When enumeration starts on the service side(it uses 4 runing threads in threadpool) my UI is freezing for several seconds (depends on total data size).

Does anybody know any way to make UI work good - without freezing in this moment?

**Update:**
Here is my ThreadPoolExecutor wrapper that i am using in service to execute estimate tasks(created like new ThreadPoolWorker(4,4,10)):

```
    public class ThreadPoolWorker {

    private Object threadPoolLock = new Object();
        private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = null;
        private ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = null;
        private List<Future<?>> futures = null;

    public ThreadPoolWorker(int poolSize, int maxPoolSize, int keepAliveTime){
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5);
        threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
        threadPool.prestartAllCoreThreads();
    }

    public void runTask(Runnable task){
        try{
            synchronized (threadPoolLock) {
                if(futures == null){
                    futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
                }
                futures.add(threadPool.submit(task));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("runTask failed. " + e.getMessage() + " Stack: " + OperationsHelper.StringOperations.getStackToString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }

    public void shutDown()
    {
        synchronized (threadPoolLock) {
           threadPool.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public void joinAll() throws Exception{
        synchronized (threadPoolLock) {
            try {

                if(futures == null || (futures != null && futures.size() <= 0)){
                    return;
                }

                for(Future<?> f : futures){
                    f.get();
                }
            } catch (ExecutionException e){
                log.error("ExecutionException Error: " + e.getMessage() + " Stack: " + OperationsHelper.StringOperations.getStackToString(e.getStackTrace()));
                throw e;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("InterruptedException Error: " + e.getMessage() + " Stack: " + OperationsHelper.StringOperations.getStackToString(e.getStackTrace()));
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here the way to start enumeration tasks that i use:

```
estimateExecutor.runTask(contactsEstimate);
```

Comment: Use Traceview to determine what you are doing on the main application thread of your UI process. You may also wish to consider getting rid of the second process, as all at is doing is adding IPC overhead and extra RAM consumption for no good reason.

Comment: I have to provide an ability to continue data transfering in case UI was closed. So i cant use one process for UI and data handling. 
- i tried switch on CPU usage indicator in the android developer options. An can say that CPU usage i high in that moment for both processes (UI & Service).
- i tried to disable enumeration of the data and it fixes the problem - UI is working fine, but i need to enumerate them (
Is it possible to decrease priority of the threads? (May be it can fix the problem?)

Comment: "I have to provide an ability to continue data transfering in case UI was closed" -- that does not require a separate process. "So i cant use one process for UI and data handling" -- other programmers can. Just looking at major-brand apps on my personal phone, Dropbox, Evernote, Remember the Milk, and TripIt are all able to "use one process for UI and data handling".

Comment: thank you for your tip. i will investigate this ability

Comment: Do you anywhere have the UI thread blocking on a result from one of your background threads?  Just moving something into a thread isn't enough; you have to let go of it so that the UI event function can promptly return, and let the result arrive asynchronously later via a messaging or event scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say you did not provided enough information (the part of the code you suspect as the cause..)
but from my knowledge and experience I can make an educated guess -

you are probably performing code on the UI thread (main thread) that it execution taking a while.  I can also guess that this code is : querying cotacts / gallery provider for all the data..

in case you don't know - `Service` callback methods also been executed from the main thread (the UI thread..)  unless explicitly you run them from `AsyncTask` / another thread,  and querying content providers and processing it returned cursor  for data can also be heavy operation that need to be executed from another thread for not blocking the main UI thread.

after removing the code performing this expensive queries to another thread - there is no reason you'll experience any freezing.

Comment: Thanks you for your time, i have updated my post. Do you think that my threads tasks running in UI thread?

Comment: If you can't figure it out by inspection, you could easily have them log their thread ID and compare it to one logged by the UI.

Comment: @Avega768: I don't see in the code you provided anything related to explicitly fetching all user contacts / photos.  where is that code?